# How update a parameter via Javascript in CDE

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to create an interactive dashboard with CDE and I would like a parameter to be set
when I click on the element of a treemap.

I've created a parameter and can display (via a text component), I also wrote a clickAction which display the desired value I want to set to the parameter. The question is, how do I set the parameter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, simply:

```
Dashboards.fireChange('paramname', paramvalue);
```